# Is TDataSet asynchronous loading thread safe if it's connected to GUI control?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, asynchronous, thread-safety, tthread

I would like to asynchronously load data in a TDataSet using a TThread descendant. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I suppose there couldn't be any problem if dataset isn't connected to any GUI control but.. What if TDataSet is linked to a TDataSource that's linked to a GUI control? Is myThread.synchronize needed?

Comment: I think you'd better disconnect it until your thread is done. You can catch events and progress in that thread and update gui when needed. Of course,you want to synchronize() those update calls.

Comment: Yes, you must disconnect them because data links such as the one for DB grid does not update the control in a thread safe manner (the rest of the layers use direct calls). You can disconnect the data set from the data source by doing `DataSource.DataSet := nil;` and assign it back when you're done with your thread work, for instance. P.S., if you were calling dataset methods through `Synchronize`, you wouldn't need a thread.

Comment: After disconnecting, in cases which other threads doesn't change the DataSet object, I can work on TDataSet without any problem?